# Is there a difference between the 'acer-wmi' and 'acer_wmi' drivers?

Tags: drivers, syntax

Is there a difference between drivers acer-wmi, and acer_wmi?

Sometimes on my computer I see the driver acer-wmi and acer_wmi, they are also both quoted in forums interchangeably.

Comment: Need a little more context here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no difference**.

`acer-wmi.ko` is the name of the module (driver) file, while the actual module, following Linux naming conventions, is called `acer_wmi`.

References in forums, blogs, etc. may use both conventions. Kernel logs, etc. *should* use `acer_wmi`.